# Remote Control software for Mac

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, connection, vnc

One of the things I like about Microsoft's RDC Client is that the resolution of the experience is set by the client and not, say, a physical monitor connected to the host, as is the case with VNC; the latter being the protocol used by Mac.  This means that even though I'm connecting to a notebook with a 1280x800 physical resolution, via RDC I can run it at 2560x1600 on my 30" monitor.

However, that only seems to work for RDC.  Does anyone know of something I can run on the Mac that will allow me to remotely control it at a different resolution than what is physically set?

TIA,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I've found [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) to be quite good, though I can't recall if it does exactly what you ask. But since it's free it should be easy for you to find out.

Comment: CoRD is an RDP client, but not a server.

Comment: Actually, CoRD is a Remote Desktop client.  I'm looking for a client that lets me connect to a Mac, not from a Mac.  

As for the feature I want, by default the Mac uses VNC which matches the physically attached screen resolutions whereas Remote Desktop can have its resolution for the session set by the client. I'm looking for a mac-based solution that does the same thing. (Reason is I have a quad-monitor mac system with a 30", 2x24" and a 21" so VNC and its native resolution makes everything microscopic.  Yes I can view a single monitor at a time, but that becomes a pain.)

Answer (score 0):

There's apple remote desktop if you can afford it.

http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

Also back to my mac which is part of the mobile me subscription I believe.

Comment: Neither of those do what I asked.  Again, like I said, they use VNC which relies on the host's physical resolution.  I am looking for something on the Mac that works like RDC on Windows in where the client, not the host, determines the desktop's resolution.

As an example, my desktop has quad monitors.  I want to connect to that desktop from my notebook and have the experience use the notebook's, not the desktop's resolution (I.e. One screen, not four, and a resolution that matches the notebook, not a physically attached monitor.)